# is it possible to schedule jobs in ruby on rails application deployed in heroku with delayed jobs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am using

ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]

Rails 4.2.4

I want to run background jobs scheduled which to be run in future like sending emails and some CRUD operations in my ruby app which is deployed in heroku.

Comment: https://github.com/resque/resque

Answer (score 0):

add `schedular` addon of heroku and create rake tasks under `/lib` folder of your rails application.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of background job do you want to use?

I've used a Redis and sidekiq on Heroku many times.

First, add a Redis add-on to your Heroku instance (doesn't really matter which).

Ensure that a Redis DB exists by accessing the add-on page.

Figure out how your application layer will communicate with this add-on (typically using a gem configuration to specify the URL of your Redis add-on).

Add a process called worker to your Procfile using your gem's documentation:

```
worker: bundle exec jobs:work
```